# How to use multiple action buttons in R Shiny to manipulate a data frame consecutively?

Tags: r, shiny

I am trying to build a Shiny App with 4 action buttons that manipulate 1 data frame. I tried to make my action buttons working on the data frame consecutively, say, by clicking the **Delete The First Row** 49 times and I can get the last row of `cars`. I've written a ui.R for that:

```
#ui.R
shinyUI(pageWithSidebar(
  headerPanel("actionButton test"),
  sidebarPanel(
    actionButton("delete_top_1", "Delete The First Row"),
    p("Click the button to delete the first row"),
    #cars[-1, ]
    br(),
    actionButton("delete_last_1", "Delete the Last Row"),
    p("Click the button to delete the last row"),
    #cars[-nrow(cars), ]
    br(),
    actionButton("delete_top_2", "Delete the Top 2 Rows"),
    p("Click the button to delete the top 2 rows"),
    #cars[-1:-2, ]
    br(),
    actionButton("delete_last_2", "Delete the Last 2 Rows"),
    p("Click the button to delete the last 2 rows")
    #cars[-nrow(cars):-(nrow(cars)-1), ]
  ),
  mainPanel(
    tableOutput('view')
  )
))
```

However, I am stuck with the server.R part, I am thinking about using a `reactiveValue()` to replace `cars`. Could someone give me sample codes on the server.R part?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `reactiveValues()` is indeed the right choice for managing state.

I used `mtcars` dataset for presentation purposes.

```
library(shiny)
library(datasets)

ui <- shinyUI(pageWithSidebar(
  headerPanel("actionButton test"),
  sidebarPanel(
    actionButton("delete_top_1", "Delete The First Row"),
    p("Click the button to delete the first row"),
    #cars[-1, ]
    br(),
    actionButton("delete_last_1", "Delete the Last Row"),
    p("Click the button to delete the last row"),
    #cars[-nrow(cars), ]
    br(),
    actionButton("delete_top_2", "Delete the Top 2 Rows"),
    p("Click the button to delete the top 2 rows"),
    #cars[-1:-2, ]
    br(),
    actionButton("delete_last_2", "Delete the Last 2 Rows"),
    p("Click the button to delete the last 2 rows")
    #cars[-nrow(cars):-(nrow(cars)-1), ]
  ),
  mainPanel(
    tableOutput('view')
  )
))

server <- function(input, output, session){
  vals <- reactiveValues(data = mtcars) # Initialize vals$data

  observeEvent(input$delete_top_1, vals$data <- vals$data[-1, ])
  observeEvent(input$delete_top_2, vals$data <- vals$data[-c(1,2), ])
  observeEvent(input$delete_last_1, vals$data <- vals$data[-nrow(vals$data), ])
  observeEvent(input$delete_last_2, vals$data <- vals$data[-c(nrow(vals$data) - 1, nrow(vals$data)), ])

  output$view <- renderTable(vals$data)

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Wow! It worked just as what I expected! Thank you so much @GyD, I shall spend time reading about `reactiveValues()` and `observeEvent()` !